# Finding the repelling fixed point of an exponential, knowing only its attracting one

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ds.dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

This question has been bugging me for a while, I have an answer that is working sufficiently for the program I'm using, but it is a tad slow, and let's say imprecise. It is not an overtly difficult question, and for that I assume someone smarter than me has already found a better explanation.

To begin, we take a value $y \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|\log(y)| < 1$. Then we look at the exponential:

$$
b^z = e^{\log(y) z/y}\\
$$

The value $b = y^{1/y}$ is inside what we call the Shell-Thron region, in the tetration circles. This is the area in which:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp_b^{\circ n}(0) \,\,\text{converges}
$$

Or, where the iterated exponential converges.

Now, to highlight the question, we can start with $1 < b < e^{1/e}$. The exponential $b^z$ has two fixed points on the real line. There is an attracting fixed point $1 < y < e$ and a repelling fixed point $\mu > e$. Both of which satisfy:

$$
e^{\log(y)/y} = e^{\log(\mu)/\mu}\\
$$

This relationship carries over for all $|\log(y)| < 1$, not just when it is real valued. From here, my question is simple.

Can anyone describe the holomorphic function:

$$
\begin{align}
f(y): \{y \in \mathbb{C} : \, |\log(y)| < 1\} &\to \{\mu \in \mathbb{C} :\,|\log(\mu)| > 1\}\\
\frac{\log f(y)}{f(y)} &= \frac{\log(y)}{y}\\
\end{align}
$$

And when restricted to real values:

$$
f(y): (1,e) \to (e , \infty)\\
$$

The manner I am solving this currently is a tad involved. But if $h(z) = \frac{\log(z) y}{\log(y)} = \log_b(z)$, and $h^{\circ n}$ are the iterates of $h$:

$$
f(y) = \lim_{n\to\infty} h^{\circ n}(e)\\
$$

This formula works on the real line, and moderately well in the complex plane. But I'm not certain if it works for all $|\log(y)| < 1$, there may be issues. It essentially runs off the basis that $e$ is in the Julia set of $b^z$, and/or in the attracting basin of the fixed point $\mu$ for the logarithm $\log_b(z)$. I don't know if this is true universally though, just for a large part of the domain in question.

This has been bugging me, and any help is appreciated. In essence, does anyone know any good ways of computing/describing/constructing $f$, other than the way I mentioned?

Comment: Perhaps I did not understand the problem well but I have the impression that Newton's method should work well for solving your problem numerically.

Comment: From a theoretical point of view, you consider a two-sheeted covering branching above $e$ of an open set of $\mathbb C$. It is thus essentially conjugate to the map $x\longmapsto (x-e)^2$ and you want a conjugating holomorphic function. You can perhaps guess the series expansion of the conjugating map at $e$.

Comment: @RolandBacher Yeah, you can run Newton's method to find it, but that just feels like cheating to me. Plus it's difficult to run Newton's method and keep track of the Taylor expansion, which is kind of pivotal for me in the program I'm writing in Pari-GP.

Could you explain more so what you mean by your remarks on conjugacy. Are you saying, there should be some map $h$ such that $h(f(y)) = (h(y)-e)^2$? And through brute force pull out the Taylor expansion of $h$ at $e$? Just so I understand you better.

Comment: @RolandBacher I should clarify that I not only want to calculate $f(y)$--which is super fast using Newton's method. I want to calculate $f(y) = f(y_0) + f'(y_0)(y-y_0) + f''(y_0)(y-y_0)^2/2...$ in an efficient manner. I can already beat newton's method pointwise, by pulling out taylor series, but it is a hack job. So I'm wondering if there's some analytic process which could remedy the situation. The expression $\lim_{n\to\infty} \log^{\circ n}_{y^{1/y}}(e)= f(y)$ is accurate almost everywhere I've tested--and it calculates the Taylor series. Newton always fails for this.

Comment: Conjugacy was ill chosen: There should be a holomorphic homeomorphism $h$ and a holomorphic function $g$ such that $f(y)=g(h(y)^2)$ (i.e. your function is an even function). We do not care about $g$, all the interesting stuff happens with the homeomorphism $h$. I hope this is a bit clearer (but generally the fog lifts only completely when dirtying hands which I did not do).

Comment: @RolandBacher Honestly this helps a lot. I understand in a partial sense what you mean. But you gave me an idea of how to write $f$, that uses this intuition while still keeping Taylor series data. Thank you a lot, I think I can take it from here. I see the general direction you are suggesting, I have a bunch of tools in my toolbelt from here. I really appreciate your answer and your suggestions. It may seem dumb, but I'm that much closer to seeing the solution. Thanks :)

Comment: @RolandBacher Yes, I got it. Thanks a lot for your help. Primarily the reminder that $e$ was a branching point, and that the branching was 2 dimensional (looks like $x^2$). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I found the answer to this problem! It's a tad different than I thought, so I'll give the run down. Special thanks to @RolandBacher for getting me to think about $e$ as a branching point. The answer was simpler than I thought once I dug through it.

Let

$$
g(y) = y^{1/y}\\
$$

Then, there exists two branches to the inverse of this function, call them $h_1$ and $h_2$. The first satisfies:

$$
h_1 : (1,e^{1/e}) \to (1, e)\\
$$

And the second satisfies:

$$
h_2 : (1,e^{1/e}) \to (e,\infty)\\
$$

This is just standard calculus when looking at the self-root function. Thereby, our function $f$ is just the analytic continuation of the expression:

$$
f(y) = h_2(y^{1/y})\\
$$

This solves the problem entirely. I apologize for asking a question when the answer was right in front of me, lmao. Thanks for the help, Roland!